# ionic2: how to set image above image opacity?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm using Ionic2 and I want to make image and set an icon above the image when clicking the image I will upload image : 
this is my code:

```css
img {
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://cdn.business2community.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/profile-picture.jpg"/><br/>
        <button clear id="chgImg">Change Image</button><br/>
```

I want to set :

```
<ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon>
```

above the image and in the center of it, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a container to the image and button

```
.container{
     position: relative;
 }
```

Add the icon inside container
And set it's position to absolute.

Comment: I want the icon to be above the image not the button

Comment: Yes. Same logic. position absolute on the icon.